# How to redirect a http subdomain to a https?

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, subdomain

I tried reading many answers, but couldn't figure out how to solve this in .htaccess

Force:

http://subdomain.domain.com

to

https://subdomain.domain.com

Is it this simple?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://subdomain.domain.com [R,L]
```

Comment: Yes, I need when someone types http://subdomain.domain.com redirects to the same subdomain but with https

Comment: The code you posted  also redirects the maindomain to subdomain.

Comment: Thanks. How can I solve this then?

Comment: Have you tried the code on your server? and what error are you getting with this?

Comment: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Dit you serch for 'rewrite http to https'?